# What are the values of true and false and who set them?

Tags: javascript, boolean

I'm learning javascript and I just got started with variables and data types. But I'm having difficulty understanding where true/ false are set.

I've tried to use:

`console.log(true);` and `console.log(false);`

But I got true/false on the console as is, I thought these "words" (variables) were set by me using:

`var true = whatever;` and
`var false = whatever;`

What are the valuse of `true` and `false`? Where are they set and can I change them?

Comment: those are reserved keywords

Comment: 'true' and 'false' are reserved keywords. You can't reassign a value to them..!

Comment: the name is the value. it is no placeholder like a variable.

Comment: you can't set `var true = whatever;` `var false = whatever;` those are reserved keywords and will raise an exception

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Boolean_literal

Comment: The value of `true` is `true` just like the value of `5` is `5` or the value of `"hello"` is `"hello"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values `true` and `false` are reserved keywords called Booleans in JavaScript - and they're set automatically by every JavaScript engine. JavaScript has a lot of these, nearly all of which you use without even thinking (`var`, `function`, `console.log`, etc.).

`true` and `false`, when evaluated to numbers, are `0` and `1`:

```js
console.log(+true);
console.log(+false);
```

Answer (score 1):

`true` and `false` **are** values (they are boolean literals). They are not variables.

See [data types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Data_types).